# Dnsmasq configuration with network-manager

Tags: router

I would like to acces my Home-Server via my DynDNS Adress from inside my local network. I can configure the etc/hosts file on each PC but I also have SmartPhones on which I can not do so.
So I figured I need a Dnsmasq on my Server, configure my router to use the server as DNS and configure Dnsmasq.
The only purpose of this is to access the DynDNS address within my network without editing host files.

So far I installed it on my debian 10 Server. Following this guide:
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dnsmasq/

I have to edit /etc/resolve.conf but it is managed by Network Manager, so I can not do it.
I run the server without desktop and I am not familiar how to use nm-cli to achieve my goal.

Maybe someone who has done similiar things can help me configuring dnsmasq, because I am not really familiar with setting up a DNS-Server.

Answer (score 0):

I found this little tidbit on tecmint and it was very useful.

11. The /etc/resolv.conf file is maintained by a local daemon especially the NetworkManager, therefore any user-made changes will be overwritten. To prevent this, write-protect it by setting the immutable file attribute (disabling write access to the file) using the chattr command as shown.

## chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

## lsattr /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to achieve you'll need to use `dnsmasq` as a Network Manager plugin.

Please have a look at [this article](https://fedoramagazine.org/using-the-networkmanagers-dnsmasq-plugin/) to have some place to start.